# How does "ClusterRoleBinding" works and how do i get rid of it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, shinyproxy

It finally worked! I was able to host my ShinyApp over an EKS cluster with ShinyProxy and Kubernetes!

Unfortunately, I have now noticed that it doesn't quite work as I had imagined.

Briefly about my wishful thinking:
My website integrates the load balancer via an iFrame. Users who visit my website can upload their data (without logging in or similar) and have it analysed accordingly in the tool. For this purpose, they should have their own R-session (via Shinyproxy).
This means that the simultaneous users cannot look at each other's data and the evaluations run in parallel on the cluster, as everyone has their own R session.

How it is currently:
There are two users: admin and guest. If you call the load balancer or ShinyProxy (via the load balancer), you have to authenticate yourself accordingly. Depending on the role with which you log in, you get your own session.
However, if I log on to 2 devices as admin, my changes are only processed one after the other, but not in parallel (due to the role binding?).

As soon as I remove the authentication and the user tries to access the tool without authentication, the tool no longer starts.

I suspect that it is due to my "sp-authentication.yaml" file. The code looks like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: shinyproxy-auth
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Without being an expert, I suspect it is because of the "ClusterRoleBinding". I have tried to find out more about this, but to no avail.

If you need more background information, you can find it here:

[Tutorial after I proceeded](https://github.com/z0ph/ShinyProxyOnEKS/blob/master/doc/3-ShinyProxy-Deploy.md)

[git-Repo from which the sp-authentication.yaml is](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-config-examples/tree/master/03-containerized-kubernetes)

If you need more info, feel free to contact me! Thank you!

Comment: That's a Kubernetes-level object that connects together two other Kubernetes objects.  It seems unlikely that it would affect your application, though without any code or the server error log it's hard to tell.

Comment: ClusterRoles and ClusterRoleBindings define with which kubernetes resources a user or serviceaccount can interact and what he can do with them. Think about it like different users odn a computer with different access levels. e.g. administrator has all privileges on all resources, whereas a normal user might only be able to view resources but not to edit them. as @David Maze said the issue is most likely not the clusterrolebinding

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Hello! Sadly not - we decided to switch the hosting model to shinyapps.io due to easy deployment, deadlines and costs.